# maven: property not replaced in path (to read second other property file)

Tags: java, maven, properties

I already tried some answers of similar endeavors but nothing quite fits with what I'm trying to achieve...

This is what I'm trying to do:

I'm trying to build (filter) property files based on (other) property files.

We have a property file which contain general properties. That file (default.properties for now) is read and parsed like a charm.

Then, we also would like to have specific properties depending on environment.
(I know, not good practice, but this is the best solution since we have independent builds on different machines and generating all of the properties everywhere is not handy)

That's where we get into trouble...

When specifying a path containing a property (targetEnvironment in this case) it doesn't get filled in with it's value.

- I already tried switching phases (generate-resources/initialize/process-resources);
- use cli property with: `mvn clean install -DtargetEnvironment=NT`
- use a profile called with:

(inside the pom)

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>nt</id>
        <properties>
            <targetEnvironment>NT</targetEnvironment>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

This is (part of) the current pom (only relevant parts are shown):

```
<project>

(some maven code)

    <build>

    (other maven code)

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execution1</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <files>
                                <file>src/env_properties/env/${targetEnvironment}/specific.properties</file>
                            </files>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execution2</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <files>
                                <file>src/env_properties/env/default/default.properties</file>
                            </files>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-echo-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>echo</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <echos>
                        <echo>Animal: src/env_properties/env/${targetEnvironment}/specific.properties</echo>
                        <!-- prints: src/env_properties/env/NT/specific.properties -->
                    </echos>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/extra-resources</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/env_properties/base</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Strange thing is,

if I replace ${targetEnvironment} with the literal 'NT' it works, so the mechanism works, only not the replacement...

I also tried to change versions for the plugins but some versions even make it worse...

Any Ideas?

Thanks,

S.

edit: another strange thing, if I build without the `-DtargetEnvironment=NT` parameter I get a build failed because:

```
[INFO]
[INFO] --- properties-maven-plugin:1.0.0:read-project-properties (execution1) @ batch3 ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.644 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-21T15:55:11+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 41M/459M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:properties-maven-plugin:1.0.0:read-project-properties (execution1) on project batch3: Properties could not be loaded from File: C:\path\to\src\env_properties\env\${targetEnvironment}\specific.properties -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to solve the original problem but I found something that does what I want to do:

If you have a property file (with values to replace values in other property files; for instance:)

(top-level.properties)

```
ejb.server.url=not yet defined
ejb.server.user=not yet defined
ejb.server.pwd=not yet defined
```

and a specific property file (based on a property provided at build time by calling for instance `mvn clean install -DtargetEnvironment=NT`)

(src\env_properties\env\NT\specific.properties)

```
garrafra.doesntbestaat=anotherTest
```

then the first property can be read like this:

```
    <build>

        (some maven code)

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>execution1</id>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <files>
                            <file>src/env_properties/env/default/top_level.properties</file>
                        </files>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        (other maven code)

    </build>
```

properties in this file can be used to retrieve (for instance the path) for more specific property files.

...and (in the same  tag of course) the specific property file(s) can be read (and applied for filtering) like this:

```
    <build>

        (some maven code)

        <filters>
            <filter>src/env_properties/env/${targetEnvironment}/specific.properties</filter>
        </filters>

        (other maven code)

    </build>
```

Providing this in the properties-maven-plugin doesn't work for some reason...

Both the general (top level) properties as the specific (environment dependent ones) get filled in:

(vanilla.properties (before):)

```
java.naming.provider.url=${ejb.server.url}
java.naming.security.principal=${ejb.server.user}
java.naming.security.credentials=${ejb.server.pwd}

blie=${garrafra.doesntbestaat}
```

(after)

```
java.naming.provider.url=not yet defined
java.naming.security.principal=not yet defined
java.naming.security.credentials=not yet defined

blie=anotherTest
```